# Injecting custom headers into ServletRequest in Spring Boot JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, custom-headers

I have a requirement to inject custom headers into every request a spring boot application is getting, for this, I have written some code but it seems it is not doing its work. For a brief, I have implemented the Filter interface and defined the doFilter method, extended the HttpServletRequestWrapper class, and overridden getHeader() and getHeaderNames() method to take into account the custom headers I am reading from the properties file.

But, the moment I get into the controller and check the request I am not getting my custom headers that were set through the MyReqWrapper. Below is the code, I've also tried searching it in Stackoverflow but couldn't find the solution on what is/could be wrong here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Also, please point me on how to test whether custom headers are actually set or not.

**This is Filter implementation**

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ReqFilter implements Filter {
    private static final String CUSTOMHEADERENABLED = "customheadersenabled";
    private static final String CUSTOMHEADERCOUNT = "customheaderscount";
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {
            boolean customHeadersEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(env.getProperty(CUSTOMHEADERENABLED, "false"));
            int count = Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty(CUSTOMHEADERCOUNT, "0"));

            if (customHeadersEnabled && count > 0) {
                MyReqWrapper myReq = new MyReqWrapper((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
                myReq.processMyHeaders(count, env);
                filterChain.doFilter(customRequest, servletResponse);
            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            }
        }
        catch(ServletException ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //
    }
}
```

**This is custom request wrapper extending HttpServletRequestWrapper**

```
final class MyReqWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private static final String CUSTOMHEADERPREFIX = "header1";
    private final Map<String, String> myHeaders;

    public MyReqWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        myHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        String headerValue = myHeaders.get(name);

        if (headerValue != null){
            return headerValue;
        }
        return ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeader(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(myHeaders.keySet());

        Enumeration<String> headerNames = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String n = headerNames.nextElement();
            set.add(n);
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(set);
    }

    public void processMyHeaders(int headerCount, Environment env) {
        while(headerCount > 0){
            String [] headerKeyValue = Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty(String.format("%1$s%2$s", CUSTOMHEADERPREFIX, headerCount--)))
                    .split(":");
            this.myHeaders.put(headerKeyValue[0], headerKeyValue[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpServletRequest is an interface, see the class implementing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved for me and I forgot to update this with an answer.

So the problem was I was using `HttpServletRequest` class from two different namespaces in the ReqFilter and controller classes, namely one from **"org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttpServletRequest"** and another from **"javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"**.

Once I used uniform namespace in both the files I could access the headers from controller classes.

Comment: Which namespace did you end up using?